# How to read properties file using org.apache.commons.configuration2?

Tags: java, apache, scala

I'm trying to read properties file using org.apache.commons.configuration2 and getting error below please let me know where I'm doing wrong I'm taking help with given link https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/quick_start.html

```
File:- xyz.properties

driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521/xxxx.xxxx"
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
input_file = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\test\\src\\main\\resources\\xxxx.xlsx"


code:- File.scala

import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.{Configurations}

object Configuration {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val config = new Configurations();
    val configs = config.properties(new File("xyz.properties"));


    val inputFile = configs.getString("input_file")

    val userName = configs.getString("username")
    val password = configs.getString("password")
    val driver = configs.getString("driver")
    val url = configs.getString("url")


    println("Inside config" + inputFile )       
}
}

Error :-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:602)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:614)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileBasedBuilder(Configurations.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.propertiesBuilder(Configurations.java:238)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.properties(Configurations.java:282)
    at com.rxcorp.italy.config.Configuration$.<init>(File.scala:8)
    at com.rxcorp.italy.config.Configuration$.<clinit>(Configuration.scala)
    at com.rxcorp.paneldataloading.ItalyPanelData$.main(File.scala:19)
```

**sbt file**

```
name := "xxx.xxxx.xxxxx"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

ivyScala := ivyScala.value map{ _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }


libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-configuration2" % "2.1.1"  )
```

Comment: can you include your sbt files settings (libraryDependencies) in the question.

Comment: @rogue-one I have added the sbt file please see the updated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add commons-beanutils artifact to your libraryDependencies in sbt to resolve this issue. so the `libraryDependencies` of your sbt file would look like below.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-configuration2" % "2.1.1",
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.3"
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply now i am getting this "error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/xml/MetaData"

Comment: you should add "org.scala-lang" % "scala-xml" % "2.10.6" to `libraryDependencies `

Comment: now i'm getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V

Comment: i forgot to include one more error is org.scala-lang#scala-xml;2.10.6: not found